# How to do operation on individual matches in a full line

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a [Verilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog) line like this:

```
if (i2_0&!(i2_1)) (posedge i0_0 => (o:1'b1))=(0, 0);
```

How can I convert it to a line like:

```
if (i2_0 == 1'b1 & i2_1 == 1'b0) (posedge i0_0 => (o:1'b1))=(0, 0);
```

Basically I want to search the alphanumeric strings after the first bracket of the if statement and convert each section in between the brackets or the "&"s to their equivalent logic statement.
E.g.:

`(i2_0&` becomes `(i2_0 == 1'b1 &`

and:

`!(i2_1))` becomes `i2_1 == 1'b0)`

in the above example.

Comment: And why is `i2_0&` equivalent to `i2_0 == 1'b1 &`? How did `b1` get into this? How does `!(i2_1)` become `i2_1 == 1`? That seems like exactly the inverse of what it was. Shouldn't that be `i2_1==0`?

Comment: The second line is a logical equivalent of the first one.
1'b1 means, it's a 1 bit binary variable and takes value 1. Similarly 1'b0 means, it's a binary value with value 0.
Hence logical equivalent statement of !(a) is "a == 1'b0"

Comment: Um, in what language? I don't know that syntax. You might want to clarify what language logic this should follow.

Comment: The language mentioned is verilog.

Comment: Ah, thanks, when I had first read the question, `Verilog` was not a link so I assumed it was some kind of logging software. I guess your question is understandable if you're familiar with Verilog, but you might want to define your requirements in a way that people unfamiliar with Verlilog would understand. A lot of text-processing experts won't know what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to explanation in comments:

```
sed "
# for lines which starts with if
/^if\b/{
    /==/! {
        # add logic statement to first alphanums after ( 
        s/\((\w\+\)/\1 == 1b'1 /
        # add logic statement to second alphanums after & if it is present 
        s/\(&\!\?(\?\w\+\)/\1 == 1b'1 /
        # if ! sign in section replace 1 by 0 at the end of statement 
        s/\!(\([^']*'\)1 )/ \10 /g
          }
       }
" file
```

Other variant - remove everithing except part which will be modified, change it, than construct full line back:

```
sed "/^if\b/{
        /==/!{
            h
            s/if (.*) //
            x
            s/if (\(.*\)) (.*/\1/
            s/\w\+/& == 1'b1 /g
            s/!(\(.*\)1 )/ \10/g
            s/.*/if (&)/
            G
            s/\n/ /
             }
            }" file
```

Comment: Can you please explain the components of the above piece of code? I tried the full one, but unfortunately it's not working for me as such.
`1'b1` is the value assigned if the variable is without a "!" (means negation). Similarly '1'b0' is assigned to a variable within "!". E.g. `!(i2_1)` takes logical equivalent statement as  `i2_1 == 1'b0`...

Comment: @Pratap I have change code up to your comment. Please check

Comment: Thanks for the comments with explanation!
When I use the full code I am getting error like this.
`lc-sj1-4894{pratap}470: sed '/^if\b/{s/(\(\w\+\))\?/(\1 == 1b'\''1 / s/\(&!\?\)(\?\(\w\+\))\?/\1\2 == 1b'\''1/ s/!\([^'\'']*'\''\)1/ \10/g}' file > mod_file`
Error:
`/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unknown option to `s' `

I could get some output from the first part though:
`sed '/^if\b/{s/(\(\w\+\))\?/(\1 == 1b'\''1 /g}' source_file > mod_file_p1`
But the result is not desired one: I wanted the == 1'b1 conversions to happen only in the first bracket enclosure of  `if` and not other part.

Comment: @Pratap I made  `!` escaped and exchage single to double quotes

Comment: The error still persises as soon as the second and third sed sections are added.
`lc-sj1-4894{pratap}513: sed "/^if\b/{s/(\(\w\+\))\?/(\1 == 1b'1 / s/\(&\!\?\)(\?\(\w\+\))\?/\1\2 == 1b'1/ s/\!\([^']*'\)1/ \10/g}" source_file > ! ver_file`
Error:
`/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unknown option to `s'`
and the other problem (tested with the first section only) it modifies the contents outside the bracket of the first if which is error.
Eg it should be
`if (...) (posedge i0_0 => (o:1'b1))=(0, 0);`
But code gives `if (...) (posedge i0_0 == 1b'1 => (o:1'b1))=(0, 0);`

Comment: @Pratap How you put expression in to term? There should be `;` or `\n`ewline(just copy+paste script in answer as it is) before each `s/...`

Comment: Most cases it's working!
Few issues cases though:
`if (!(i1_0)&!(i1_1)) --> if ( i1_0 == 1'b1 )&!(i1_1 == 1'b0)` (not in desired lines)
should have been ` if ( i1_0 == 1'b0 ) & (i1_1 == 1'b0)`
It was silly of me that I didn't know to insert ; in between line breaks
What does h; do? similarly //;x ?   ;G; ?
Are these some key words?
There is another catch. In some lines of d file, the if statement is already having the == 1'b0 format & I don't want to touch them. Is there any way by which I can do the replacement only when there is a match of `if  (` and string `==` is not there?

Comment: @Pratap Modify - try to check. In script you have either `line break` or `;` between instructions. The better way is select full script, copy, paste to terminal and push <Enter> to execute it like it is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{\bif\s*\K\((([^()]++|\((?1)\))*)(?=\))}{
  $& =~ s{([&(])\s*(!?)\s*\(?(\w+\b)\)?(?!\s*(==|'\''))}{
   "$1$3 == 1'\''b".(0+!!$2)}gers}ges'
```